# What's the reproducing kernel of $H^1(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I would have thought to find this question here on MSE, but I couldn't find it. I know from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Common_examples that the Laplacian kernel is the reproducing kernel of $H^1(\mathbb R)$ (why is there no $\sigma$ in the norm, btw?), but I couldn't find any reference for a compact interval $[a,b]$. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is:
$$ 
K(x,y)=
\begin{cases} 
\sigma\frac{\cosh(\sigma(x - b))\cosh(\sigma (t - a))}{\sinh(\sigma(b-a))}\text{ for }a\leq t\leq x\leq b\\
\sigma\frac{\cosh(\sigma(x - a))\cosh(\sigma(t - b))}{\sinh(\sigma(b-a))}\text{ for }a\leq x\leq t\leq b.\\
\end{cases}$$
This can be checked by direct verification of the reproducing property using integration by parts from the definition of the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_a^bf(u)g(u)\,du + \frac 1 {\sigma^2}\int_a^bf'(u)g'(u)\,du$.

Complete derivation with $\sigma=1$ can be found in Section 2.11 of the script by [Schaback](http://webvm.num.math.uni-goettingen.de/schaback/teaching/Appverf_II.pdf) or in Chapter 6 Section 1.6.1 of [Berlinet/Thomas-Agnan](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402076794).

Comment: Thanks, g g. I didn't know these sources.